# Having Trouble Displaying JSON Array Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have been trying to access and display this data on a table in `HTML` for a few hours now and have gotten nowhere. I have used the `$.each` function but i believe I am somehow calling the data wrong **please correct me if i am wrong** The JSON data is laid out like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "8ef2d135-73a3-4a58-8858-733f3882290a",
    "userid": "8ef2d135-73a3-4a58-8858-733f3882290a",
    "name": "MN-Carven",
    "placement": 1,
    "platform": "PC",
    "value": 66.29059172668
  },
  {
    "id": "b5af3e4f-8c43-48e4-8d04-e8adf0ae9808",
    "userid": "b5af3e4f-8c43-48e4-8d04-e8adf0ae9808",
    "name": "Tchanos.MTLK",
    "placement": 2,
    "platform": "PC",
    "value": 65.32935808926
  },
  {
    "id": "ee2fcc61-a8d9-4b57-8837-297ace438e3e",
    "userid": "ee2fcc61-a8d9-4b57-8837-297ace438e3e",
    "name": "Lion__.",
    "placement": 3,
    "platform": "PC",
    "value": 57.44590079297
  }
]
```

It is my understanding that i can access an array by using a `$.each` function in javascript. I will post my javascript below. **I am wanting to display multiple categories I.E: id, name, value etc..**

```
$(function() {
  var aliases = [];
  $.getJSON('leaderboard.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.aliases, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.placement + "</td>" + "</tr>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#leaderboard tbody");
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the `HTML` for the table:

```
<table id="leaderboard">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Place</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I was so sure that I had been correct in using `$.each`, but i believe i need some further guidance, **any links to docs relating to my problems are welcome**, thank you.

Comment: What is the resulting HTML when you run the jQuery code? How do you want it to be different?

Comment: what do you mean by "calling the data wrong"?  what specifically is the part that's not working?  are there any errors in your browser console?  have you tried calling `console.log(data);` inside your `getJSON` callback?

Comment: the result is nothing, it is almost as if it is broken, I think that i may be using my javascript wrong.

Comment: Does your JSON look like this `{"aliases": [..array]}`? because that's how you access it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, you need to log what data is and see if you have any errors (press F12 in the browser to open developer tools).

Comment: I'm convinced it's `$.each(data)`.

The JSON isn't:
`{
aliases: [{
...
},
...]
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem was my JQuery

Here is how this is solved:

```
$.getJSON('leaderboard.json', (data) => {
const tableData = data.reduce((pre, curr) => {
  return pre + `<tr><td>${curr.name}</td><td>${curr.placement}</td></tr>`;
}, '');

$(tableData).appendTo('#leaderboard tbody');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you're trying to iterate over `data.aliases`, but aliases is not a part of the data object.  Also, take a look at the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function for building your table body string. I think what you're looking for here could be accomplished with:

```
$.getJSON('leaderboard.json', (data) => {
    const tableData = data.reduce((pre, curr) => {
      return pre + `<tr><td>${curr.name}</td><td>${curr.placement}</td></tr>`;
    }, '');

    $(tableData).appendTo('#leaderboard tbody');
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, i will give this a try.

Comment: this works!! thank you sir! I will be reading up on the 'reduce' function.